# sending binary body with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, protocol-buffers

I'm using JMeter 2.10.
I'm looking for a way to send a binary POST body (Protobuf payload) with HTTP Request.
To be clear - I'm not uploading a file.
Maybe there is a way to encode byte codes in Body Data textarea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try HTTP Raw Request sampler in JMeter plugin: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/. You can get it via extra set of JMeter plugin:  http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasSet/

Comment: Nope, RawRequest uses RawDataSource which also uses files to pass in the binary data.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly getting your question and you need the data to be URL-encoded prior to being sent you can wrap your binary data into [__urlencode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function

`${__urlencode(A string containing weird characters like @ & * # and ")}`

```
POST http://example.com/

POST data:
A+string+containing+weird+characters+like+%40+%26+*+%23+and+%22
```

Alternatively you can use any suitable pre-processor. The most powerful of them is [Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) which provides full access to JMeter context and engine and allows to execute arbitrary Beanshell (Java) code.

Answer (score -4):

JMeter is also support the Protocol-buffers. You just need to add the contentType = application/octet-stream in HTTP Header Manager.

[image]

Thanks.
Atif Mehar